# Accumulative recursion

Tags: python, recursion

Given a list of strings, I need to produce a new string by combining all strings' first character. My solution:

```
def K(lst):
    if lst == []:
        return ""
    else:
        return lst[0][0] + K(lst[1:])
```

It works, but I'm sure that's not accumulative recursion.
I also tried to attempt this question by using accumulative recursion, but I couldn't figure out the correct solution.

```
def K(lst):
    acc = ""
    if lst == []:
        return acc
    else:
        acc = acc + lst[0][0]
        return K(lst[1:])
```

I don't know how to mutate `acc`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't declare your accumulator inside of your recursive function because on each call it will be redefined. You need to make it an argument to your function, a common idiom for this is to create a helper function that has the accumulator in it's definition:

```
def K(lst):
    return _K(lst, [])

def _K(lst, acc):
    if lst == []:
       return acc
    else:
       head, tail = lst[0], lst[1:]
       return _K(tail, acc + head[0])
```

Comment: Matter of preference - ```if not lst:``` appeals to me.

Comment: I never really liked that idiom,  but to each their own

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
def K(lst, s=""):
    if lst == []: return s
    else:         return K(lst[1:], s+lst[0][0])
```

Although this has the structure of accumulative recursion, I am not sure the Python interpretor can actually convert this internally to accumulative recursion.

Comment: I had a solution based, as yours, on a default argument but yours is way more elegant, especially for the way you mutate `s`...

Comment: The eagerly awaited 1liner: `def K(l,s=""):return s if l=="" else  K(l[1:],s+l[0][0])`

Comment: @ssm you are correct, the python interpreter doesn't optimize tail recursion

Comment: @HunterMcMillen  I think its high time Python introdces some sort of object/function/whatever which could cast a variable into a special object which *could* be used for tail recursion. But then again, I am not a Python hacker and way to lazy to do it myself. I'll just patiently wait for someone else to do it :).

Comment: @gboffi I think elegance is moot when the code is ineffectual. But thank you nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(ll,final):
    if len(ll)==1:
        return final+ll[0][0]
    else:
        return func(ll[1:],final+ll[0][0])

final=""
ll=["abc","bcd","cde"]


print func(ll,final)
```

You can try this.

Answer (score 0):

I would not expose the inner function:

```
def K(lst):
    def sub(lst, acc):
        if lst:
            return sub(lst[1:], acc + lst[0][0])
        return acc
    return sub(lst, "")
```

then

```
>>> print K(["abc","bcd","cde"])
abc
```

---

FWIW, there is a way to mimic what you were trying to do, but it is **bad style** and only works in Python 3 because it needs *nonlocal* :

```
def K(lst):
    acc = ""
    def sub(lst):
        if lst:
            nonlocal acc # Python3 only
            acc = acc + lst[0][0]
            return sub(lst[1:])
        return acc
    return sub(lst)

>>> print(K(["abc","bcd","cde"]))
abc
```